# How are shared libraries addressed in each processes memory?

Tags: c, linux, executable, elf

From what I understand:

When you compile code into a binary there is no need to translate the addresses in that binary. Since each process has it's own memory space, the addresses used in the binary file can be used at runtime.

However if you have a shared library, how does that get mapped into that processes memory space? If the library code uses virtual memory addresses they'd have to be changed for each process where the library is mapped to a different virtual memory address.

I'm not very experienced in this stuff (as you can probably guess), so sorry if anything is incredibly wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about Linux, but it is my understanding that on Windows, in process 2, if it needs to load a (shared) dll already loaded into process 1, the memory image is shared _if_ the address range where the dll is loaded in process 1 is available in process 2, otherwise two copies of the image are in memory, one for each base address. The executable, being the first module loaded in each address space (except for kernel, which is always present) is always loaded at its preferred address, usually 0x400000.

Comment: that is taken care by OS and its MMU [more read](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Comment: You want to look at Position independent code, and loader fixups, but thats probably beyond the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Not sure If I'm looking in the right direction, but I think what I'm interested in is how a dynamic linker works and how that converts symbols to addresses at runtime

Comment: I found this answer https://www.quora.com/How-does-dynamic-linking-work?share=1 more importantly part 3 of his answer, which suggests that at runtime an offset is added to all function calls within the library. This sounds quite inefficient that you have to add a constant before every function call / jump within a library. Is this functionality provided by the CPU or is it just the cost of having a shared library?

Comment: @user1937198 I don't think it's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, references to shared libraries are resolved by default when the library is effectively called in your code. This is called lazy biding. Thus all binaries are not executable by the processor. Most of them are in fact interpreted (see `/lib64/ld-linux-*.so`).

To perform that, the ELF binary contains two specific tables :

- the Procedure linkage table (PLT)
- the Global offset table (GOT)

The code you're executing references the PLT which performs the redirections. On the first call the GOT will contain a callback address which if executed jumps to the loader which will resolve the address to the dynamic library. The library is mapped in the virtual memory of your program, even though it is only present once in your physical memory.

You're using virtual memory so the addresses seen by your processes will be likely different thus the use of one GOT per process. As for the use of two tables : its principally for security reasons so you're never executing instructions from a writable page.

You can disable lazy biding if you wish by setting the `LD_BIND_NOW` environment variable.